# Is this is an “either/or” statement or an “either/and” statement?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, conversation, neither-nor, either-or

I’m currently applying to jobs and ran across this statement in the qualifications section of one listing:

“Not currently enrolled in or completed a Bachelor’s, Master’s, or PhD in a digital marketing related field.”

Are they saying applicants should not be currently enrolled nor should they have completed their degree? Or are they instead saying they want someone who either isn’t enrolled or who has completed their degree already?

*For clarification: This is actually the full statement copied and pasted. It is listed as a bullet point under the “Minimum Qualifications” section.

Comment: The word not applies to both verbs enrolled and completed. They want someone without any of that background.

Comment: It would be useful to see the entire sentence rather than the part beginning with *Not*.

Comment: What is the beginning of the sentence? It's likely that the grammar is wrong here and that they are trying to say: *You must not be currently enrolled in or have completed a Bachelor’s, Master’s, or PhD program in a digital marketing related field.*

Comment: It’s ambiguous.

Comment: Perhaps they want someone with practical experience of working in the field but without degree-level qualifications or perhaps they want someone to train up in their own way of doing things. The pay rate might give you a clue

Comment: They're saying they don't know how to write literate English.